# importing different nested packages in npm module

Tags: javascript, node.js, babeljs

Say I have a library structure as below:

```
my-library
|-- lib
|   |
|   |-- foo
|   |   |--index.js
|   |
|   |-- bar
|       |--index.js
|
|---src
|   |-- foo
|       |-- button.js
|       |-- index.js
|   |-- bar
|       |-- button.js
|       |-- index.js
|-- package.json
```

I want to import these packages like this:

```
import { button } from 'my-library/foo'
```

```
import { button } from 'my-library/bar'
```

Is this possible?

The only way I have got it working is to import it like:

```
import { Button } from 'my-library/lib/foo'
```

I'm using Babel if that helps. Should I just transpile to the root directory and not use a `lib` dir?

I'm was looking at packages that do this such as [lodash](https://github.com/lodash/lodash) and [React Native Vector Icons](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons) where they specify what they are importing.

Similar question here: [Root directory in package.json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30302747/root-directory-in-package-json)

Comment: yes, that's what index.js is for. Have index.js export everything you want to expose using `import ... from 'my-library/foo'`. Index.js should have a series of exports looking something like this `export { button } from './button.js'`

Comment: @AdamH I've got a step further, but doesn't seem right

Answer (score 1):

ECMAScript modules (ES modules) support an [experimental](https://nodejs.org/api/documentation.html#documentation_stability_index) property in **package.json** called [exports](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_package_exports) that allows submodule aliases.

Given a **package.json** file with this config:

```
{
  "name": "my-library",
  "exports": {
    "./foo/": "./lib/foo/",
    "./bar/": "./lib/bar/"
  }
}
```

You should be able to import modules like:

```
import { button } from 'my-library/foo'
import { button } from 'my-library/bar'
```

Another option is to update your build script:

- copy `./my-library/package.json` over to
  `./my-library/lib/package.json`
- update the `main` field if needed
- publish from the `./my-library/lib` directory

Regarding updating the `main` field, you might want to consider adding a `./my-library/lib/index.js` file that exports every module from your library for consumers that want to import from a fixed path (however, in a browser environment this would increase their bundle size):

```
import { button } from 'my-library'
```