# import the current package export by the package.json name

Tags: javascript, testing, import, package.json

I'm interested to know if there's a convention that allows a person to test the expected usage of a package from within the package. Consider the following package.json:

```
{
   "name": "@place/fn",
   "version: "1.0.0"
}
```

From *within this very package*, I'd like to have a `test.js` file, with **exactly** following code:

```
import mainThing, { anotherThing } from '@place/fn';
```

Is this possible with the right directory structure or package.json configuration? I'm also fine with CommonJS syntax if that would work better.

Answer (score 4):

Ok, found an answer on this but there's a ton of other related things I found in the process that could probably help others.

First, now I understand what I wanted to do is install the current package as a *local dependency*. That can be done in the `package.json` using the following syntax found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14387210/3928045).

```
{
  "name": "@place/fn",
  "dependencies": {
    "@place/fn": "file:./"
  }
}
```

Now, I can run `npm i` to install that change and code the following test file:

```
import mainThing, { anotherThing } from '@place/fn';
```

When running the test file, the import will act as if it was installed into another package; better mimicking the intended use.

---

Another thing I discovered is that you can alias packages installed from npm using the syntax found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56134857/how-to-install-npm-package-under-alias-or-different-name).

```
"dependencies": {
  "case-1.5.3": "npm:case@^1.5.3",
  "kool": "npm:case@^1.6.1"
}
```

Which then allows you to do the following:

```
let Case = require('case-1.5.3');
let Kool = require('kool');
```

---

And finally, another thing I found is that [Node@13 allows](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/21787#issuecomment-571004805) for a new key on the `package.json` which maps directories found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48498589/3928045). There are other packages (like [`module-alias`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/module-alias)) that do something similar with the big difference being the installed solutions (ie: `module-alias`) only work from within the package you are working with. It seems like the new [`exports`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v12.x/api/esm.html#esm_package_exports) key on `package.json` will do the mapping for use in other packages.

```
// ./node_modules/es-module-package/package.json
{
  "name": "es-module-package",
  "exports": {
    "./my/": "./src/js/lib/my/"
  }
}

import thing from 'es-module-package/my/thing.js';
// Loads ./node_modules/es-module-package/src/js/lib/my/thing.js
```

---

Ultimately the purpose of all of this was to test that the style of syntaxes I provide outside the package could be tested from within the package instead of installing into another package and testing there. Now I can check that a common lodash import syntax works for my package.

```
import get from 'lodash/get'
```

(I wish I knew what the terminology was for requiring a clean, perhaps aliased,  path of a package instead of destructuring the main export.)

Answer (score 1):

To access the main export of a package from withing the package itself, add a [main entry point export](https://nodejs.org/api/packages.html#subpath-exports) to `package.json`:

```json
{
  "name": "@place/fn",
  "version: "1.0.0",
  "exports": {
    ".": "./index.js"
  }
}
```

Replace `./index.js` with the path to the main module.

Then, in `test.js`, you can import it with the expected syntax:

```js
import mainThing, { anotherThing } from '@place/fn';
```

Be careful that when the `exports` field is defined, all subpaths of the package are no longer available to external importers unless explicitly declared in `exports`. Typically, you will want at least `package.json` to be exportable beside the main module:

```json
  "exports": {
    ".": "./index.js",
    "./package.json": "./package.json"
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

When you import a package, it's up to the package.json file to tell you where to go... Say you had the following file structure

```
project
    demo
        demo-index.js
    dist
        project.cjs.js
        project.es.js
        project.umd.js
    src
        index.js
    package.json
```

You want to code your package inside `src`, build it (using something like Vite or Bili) and then inside your `demo` folder, see if the built files (inside `dist`) work as intended.

So your package.json should have:

```
{
    "name": "project",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "main": "dist/project.cjs.js",
    "module": "dist/project.es.js",
    ...
}
```

Now, inside `demo/demo-index.js` you could just import from `../src/index.js` and use the uncompiled version.

What you can also do is import from your project root directory and get the compiled version:

```
// demo/demo-index.js
import Project from "../";
```

This will import via the `package.json` file and give you the file listed under "module", i.e. `dist/project.es.js`.

Comment: I think you missed the ask here which was to get the following `import mainThing, { anotherThing } from '@place/fn';` where `@place/fn` is the package itself that I am building. I'm already aware of your example `import Project from "../";`

Comment: That entirely depends on whether you have a default export and a named export inside your package. If so, your syntax should work since an `import` command will use the ESM module in your package.

Comment: Well, that's what I'm asking; for an answer to what it depends on.