# How to structure a simple yarn package for local sharing

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6, yarnpkg

I want to create a simple yarn package that can be installed by multiple local yarn projects using `yarn add link:/path/to/package`. Imagine the package of the package to be shared looks like this

```
├── package.json
├── tsconfig.json
└── src
    ├── generated
    │   ├── abc.js
    │   ├── abc.d.ts
    │   └── def.js
    │   └── def.d.ts
```

My goal is that `abc` and `def` should be accessible like this

```js
import * from "myPackage/abc"
```

Currently if I install the above package with `yarn add link:/path/to/package` then I have to do

```js
import * from "myPackage/src/generated/abc"
```

I'm a rookie on making typescript packages so forgive me. Can someone point me in the right direction here?

I've tried the suggestion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57712063/2834295) but it doesn't make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

So it seems I need to set `exports` and `typesVersions` in `package.json`

```json
  "exports": {
    "./": "./src/generated/"
  },
  "typesVersions": {
    "*": {
      "abc": [
        "./src/generated/abc.d.ts"
      ],
      "def": [
        "./src/generated/def.d.ts"
      ],
    }
  },
```